# Passing post via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to autocomplete a form with some metadata according to the URL provided.

**Form page:**

```
<script>
function metatags() {
    var url = $('#url').val;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "inc/recoverData.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: 'url=' + url,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#domain').val(html.domain);
            $('#title').val(html.title);
            $('#description').val(html.description);
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

**PHP page**

```
    <?php

    $url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'; // WORKS
    $url = 'https://www.' . $_POST['url']; //  DOESNT WORKS
    
    $metaTags = get_meta_tags($url);
    $description = $metaTags['description'];
    $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $title = getTitle($url);
    
    $data = [
        "description" => $description,
        "domain" => $domain,
        "title" => $title
    ];
    
    echo json_encode($data);
```

If I pass url via Ajax, script doesn't works

Comment: URL !== domain or hostname. Send data as object instead `{ url: url }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are passing data incorrect. Pass the **data as an object** in ajax.
2. You are using val for value. While in Jquery, the value can be get with val().

Here is the updated Code:-

```
function metatags() {
    var url = $('#url').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "inc/recoverData.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {url: url},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#domain').val(html.domain);
            $('#title').val(html.title);
            $('#description').val(html.description);
        }
    })
}
```

You can read more in [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: The error is that $('#url').val. I have updated that line. Now test